# I can`t open visual studio project, visual start then close itself after little moments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I can`t open visual studio project, visual start then close itself after little moments. also I need to view two projects at the same time. I mean I want to open project1 in window and project2 in another window and put them next to each other that facilate my job sometimes,so I want to leave the feature of the allowance of parallel initialization(I don`t sure it is here for this reason or not, but as I found when I searched about solution for my issue I found one say to disable it and after that when I opened my two projects one of then closed itself suddenly and after littel moments the second project closed itseld also).

[problem description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InfkK.gif)

I tried
1-disable parallel initialization
2-update visual studio 2022 community to latest version 17.7.0
3-repair it from visual studio installer
4- restart my device

... no result help me please! [problem description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATCQz.gif)